# Restrict the values being passed automatically on page refresh?

Tags: php, forms

How do I restrict the values being passed when the page is refreshed in PHP?

I insert some values into a MySQL DB for the first time.  When I refresh the page, it automatically executes the query and insert the same values.  How do I stop the duplicate inserts?

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is handled by a [POST/Redirect/GET pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
The data is POSTed to the server, the server processes the data, then issues a redirect to another "harmless" page. When refreshing the page afterwards, only this harmless page is refreshed.

```
if ($_POST) {
    ... do database processing ...

    header('Location: harmless.html');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Hi deceze,                                                                       I used the above method, but it seems to be not working.I shows this error:" Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ( url.../) in harmless.php on line 174"

Comment: Also i have the script in the same page. It doesn't redirect to any other page.

Comment: @Paun Redirecting to the same page is fine as well. As for the error, please use the search box; it's about the most common PHP question ever.